# mapM putStrLn ["a", "b"] why does it show three lines?

Tags: haskell, io, monads

```
Prelude> mapM putStrLn ["a", "b"]
a
b
[(),()]
Prelude> mapM_ putStrLn ["a", "b"]
a
b
```

Why first version shows third line and second does not and where does third line comes from. I would not expect it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you put the `mapM` version in a standalone program, compile it with `ghc`, and run it, you don't get a third line from it, either:

```
$ cat demo.hs
main = mapM putStrLn [ "a", "b" ]
$ ghc demo.hs
$ ./demo
a
b
$
```

That `[(),()]` you see in `ghci` is just the return value of the `mapM` call; `ghci` automatically displays the value of every expression you enter.  (This is why `ghci` is called a Read-Evaluate-Print Loop, or REPL; the "Print" part is what you're seeing here.)

While `mapM` creates a list containing the return value of every `putStrLn` call (so you get one `()` for each element in the list),  `mapM_` discards those return values and returns `IO ()`, which `ghci` doesn't bother to display.  So you don't see an extra line from `ghci` in that case.

Comment: Actually, mapM_ returns IO (), but ghci doesn't bother printing the ().